# Should you use Genetic algorithm for an extremly large unstructured search space?

Tags: algorithms, search-problem, genetic-algorithms

My search space is discrete and in the order of $10^{1360}$, with a probably very complex fitness surface. Is it hopeless to attempt to use GA for such a problem? One fitness evaluation could take 1-3 minutes per candidate solution.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. One fitness evaluation is for one solution, not a whole generation. I edited to make it clear.

Comment: This question does not contain nearly enough information to be answerable.

Comment: You are saying that computing the fitness function for a single element in a single generation run takes 1-3 minutes? I.e. a single generation takes a few hours?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I hope still useful. There is a branch of search algorithms based on Bayesian methods. Some of these algorithms are targeted at search problems with long computation time and even may take the time necessary to evaluate a function into account when considering which parts of the space to explore to get best improvements quickly. See e.g. http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~hutter/nips2011workshop/papers_and_posters/opportunitycost.pdf

Comment: If the search space is truly unstructured then no algorithm will work besides brute force.

Answer (score 9):

No.  Just knowing the size of the search space is not enough to tell whether GA will work or not.  It also depends on the objective function (the "shape" of it), e.g., whether it is smoothly varying or not, how many local minima it has, and so on.

There is no good theory to know whether GA will work or not.  Ultimately, all you can do is try it and see.

As a side note: Generally speaking, for most problems, other approaches tend to do better than GA.  This is not a theorem; it's just experience / a rule of thumb that seems to often hold.